# Java JFrame not drawing lines in window

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, jframe

```
package Main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int width = 800;
        int height = 600;
        String title = "Test";

        JFrame display = new JFrame();
        display.setTitle(title);
        display.setSize(width, height);
        display.setVisible(true);
        display.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawLine(0, 100, 800, 300);

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
    }

}
```

I'm using Java's JFrame. So this isn't recognising the paint method and cant figure out why. I've been looking on YouTube videos and having a look to see if anyone has had similar problems, however everything I've found doesn't seem to help the problem.

when i set the background colour in the main part, it works, bit in paint, it doesn't seem to do anything and leaves it blank.

Its a white line over a black background, so i should easily be able to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an instance of `JFrame` with

```
JFrame display = new JFrame();
```

But the `JFrame` class has no logic to draw a white line on a black background. That logic is in your custom class `Main`. So instead, you should create an instance of `Main`:

```
JFrame display = new Main();
```

However, that change along still won't fix the problem because you are setting the background color of the "content pane" but trying to draw directly on the `JFrame` itself. The preferred solution here is to extend `JPanel` instead of `JFrame` and override its `paintComponent()` method. Then create an instance of your new class to use as the content pain:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MainPanel extends JPanel{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int width = 800;
        int height = 600;
        String title = "Test";

        JFrame display = new JFrame();
        display.setTitle(title);
        display.setSize(width, height);
        display.setVisible(true);
        display.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        display.setContentPane(new MainPanel());
    }

    public MainPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.black);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.drawLine(0, 100, 800, 300);
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. I call `setBackground()` in the constructor because it does not rely on the `Graphics` instance passed to `paintComponent()`. This also avoids the overhead of another function call for each render.
2. In `paintComponent()`, I call `super.panitComponent()`. This allows `JPanel` to clear the area to be painted and any other necessary initialization.

Comment: Ok this works thanks, but for future reference you must import JFrame if youre to continue using the JFrame commands. but adding all of the JPanel parts have fixed it thanks

Comment: @BenHardy Thanks for catching that. I have added the import for `JFrame` to my answer. Be sure to accept the answer which you helped you the most when the site allows you to. When you have enough reputation points, you can also vote for all questions that you find helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, I don't know much about Swing (I prefer JavaFX). However, it's clear that your Main class *is* a JFrame, so you should not make a new one within it. All of those methods you call on `display` are built in your current class. Basically, within your JFrame you made a new JFrame. However, your `paint` method was being called on the parent JFrame, which you never made visible. This solves your problem (you may have to fullscreen the window):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        int width = 800;
        int height = 600;
        String title = "Test";

        setTitle(title);
        setSize(width, height);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawLine(100, 100, 800, 300);

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.black);
    }

}
```

Comment: this has been able to set the background, but for some reason it wont draw the line. any suggestions?

Comment: Like I said, did you try full-screening the window? On mine, the line doesn't show up until I go full-screen.